# R Plotly on Apache Zeppelin

Tags: r, plotly, apache-zeppelin

Has anyone managed to use R`s plotly library on Apache Zeppelin.
I was not able to print the graphs when I run the below plotly code on Apache Zeppelin. I tried invoking the plotly-offline version too but it did not help.

```
%r 

library(plotly)
p1 <- plot_ly(x = ~rnorm(100), type = "histogram")
p1
p1 %>% offline(height=600)
```

Any workaround to display R-plotly graphs on Zeppelin?